# How to create spatial data using shiny and leaflets

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shapes, qgis

I want to create spatial data (shp data, gpkg data, geojson) using shiny and leaflet.
For example, in QGIS, I want to implement the function of Create Layer> newVectorLayer New> Shapefile Layer ... with shiny.

The geometry type I want to create is a polygon.
Therefore, I want to hit a pin on the map and create spatial data with the hit pin as the outer circumference.
Please let me know if you have a reference web page.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, check out the mapedit package.  https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2019/03/31/mapedit_leafpm.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. That's what I wanted to do!